# ¿Cómo retorno el resultado de una función si el argumento es una función?

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, callback

Tengo este ejercicio que no lo puedo resolver.

> Debes crear una Función llamada "callback" que reciba como Parámetros
> un número y una Función. Esta deberá retornar el resultado de esa
> función pasándole como argumento el número que llega por parámetro.

Ejemplo:

```
callback(5, (num)=>{return num*10}) debe retornar 50
callback(25, (num)=>{return num/5}) debe retornar 5
```

Empecé por acá y obviamente devuelve `undefined`:

```
function callback (num, funcion) {
  for(let i = 0; i <= num; i++){
```

Aquí intenté ubicar otra función. Y mi consulta es **¿se puede ubicar un `if` con este parámetro a cada uno `(num)=>{return num*10}`, dependiendo de la operación matemática?** **¿Es un código desprolijo?**

```
      }
  }

callback(5, (num)=>{return num*10}) // 50
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si funcion es una funcion, debes llamar a funcion (como llamas a una funcion?) y devolver el valor que esta devuelve (como devolves un valor?)

Comment: Busca sobre closures

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente lo mandas como variable (**minamefunction**) y lo usas como función (**minamefunction()**)

```js
function callback(num,func){
num=num+1;
return func(num);
}

function restar(num){
return num-23;
}
console.log(callback(45,restar));
```

Comment: Entiendo. En ese ejemplo se puso un numero y una operacion de base(restar y 23). Y la idea principal es que el usuario realice la cuenta que necesite, eligiendo lo que desea. Es lo que se entiende por la consigna y el ejemplo no?